# Can't find G. Segal's papers in CFT

Tags: paper-request

At various places I have seen people referring to Segal's papers in CFT as the "standard definition" of the subject. These seem to have become classics in this field. But I can't locate them on the net. I searched on arxiv,spires,Google/Scholar,AMS etc.

The papers I am referring to are (especially the fist one),

- G. Segal, The definition of conformal field theory, in: Differential geometrical methods in theoretical physics (Como, 1987), NATO Adv. Sci. Inst. Ser. C Math. Phys. Sci., 250, Kluwer Acad. Publ., Dordrecht, 1988, 165-171
- G. Segal, Two-dimensional conformal field theories and modular functors, in: Proceedings of the IXth International Congress on Mathematical Physics, Swansea, 1988, Hilger, Bristol, 1989, 22-37.
- G. Segal, The definition of conformal field theory, preprint, 1988; also in: Topology, geometry and quantum field theory, ed. U. Tillmann, London Math. Soc. Lect. Note Ser., Vol. 308. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2004, 421-577.

and on similar lines this paper by Moore and Seiberg

- G. Moore and N. Seiberg, Lectures on RCFT, in: Physics, geometry, and topology (Banff, AB, 1989), ed. H.C. Lee, NATO Adv. Sci. Inst. Ser. B Phys., 238, Plenum, New York, 1990, 263-361.

One possibility is that these are only available in the proceedings mentioned and hence only as books in some library. Are there no online copies of these?

Comment: Are these books/proceedings/volumes not available in your library?

Comment: I voted to close, because I don't think the purpose of MO is to substitute for going to the library/requesting an interlibrary loan/reading previews on google books - especially not for things like the Tillmann volume that are in print and easily available. I think MO runs the risk of getting into murky waters if people use it this way. Happily, much of what we need is openly available - for those things that are not, an occasional library visit isn't such a hardship.

Comment: Personally, I don't mind mathoverflow being used this way unless it in some way becomes disruptive.

Comment: Anirbit: Does Tata have a physical library?

Comment: I agree with Tim on the murky waters.  There's a definite distinction between asking for a reference and asking for a way to find a technically illegal copy of something.  Whilst the question does not ask for such, it doesn't _not_ ask for it.

Comment: The library I have access to does have one of the above papers. But there are lots of issues about an user taking a photocopy of an article from a book in the library. Hence it helps is some online database like arxiv has a legal copy of the article. 

Comment: @TimPerutz Tim, many of us live in poor countries without a good library. Forums to ask for help like this, or online libraries are a lifeline.

Answer (score 5):

Moore-Seiberg can be obtained from Professor Moore's webpage, see [this page](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/).

One of Segal's lectures can be found [here](http://www.cgtp.duke.edu/ITP99/segal/), which I'm afraid is different from what you requested.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.math.upenn.edu/~blockj/scfts/segal.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The first of your references is [available](http://books.google.com/books?id=_oF6meWTrSUC&pg=PA165) via Google books.

Answer (score 1):

The original article of Graeme Segal entitled "The definition of conformal field theory" has been reprinted together with comments from Segal in

*Topology, Geometry and Quantum Field Theory*,
Proceedings of the 2002 Oxford Symposium in the honour of the 60th birthday of Graeme Segal,
Edited by Ulrike Tillmann,
University of Oxford

It is unlikely to be found from a search about *Segal* but instead about *Tillmann*.

Comment: coudy, this is not the original article (which is just a few pages long), but the original essay.